Как написать сайт в виде активной mindmap карты?
Может есть какие то готовые скрипты для таких задач? Нужно чтобы кубики карты были активны как менюшки сайта и переводили на страницу текстовую либо в pop up окне выдавали текстовую информацию. Все сайты позволяющие создавать миндмэп карты не позволяют даже интегрировать карту в сайт и присваивать кубикам активность. помогите пожалуйста найти альтернативу
